# Transactional Replication from SQL Server 2008 to 2000

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server, transactional-replication

I has transactional replication from my server1 (MS SQL 2000) to server2 (MS SQL 2000) in another company (and on different network) and it worked OK. Instead of using real name of server2, I used alias referring to IP address of server2. 
Now, I try to set up transactional replication from my server3 (MS SQL 2008) to the same server2 (MS SQL 2000). I can connect to the server2 via SSMS using the same alias name. However, when I try to use it for replication, I got a message that for replication I have to use only real instance name (and the message provides that real name!). But when I try to use it, the message says that the host not found.
So, on the one hand, the server2 is perfectly “visible” and I can query the database from SSMS, but on the other hand it is not “visible” to set up replication.
Any thoughts?

Thank you,

YG

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to server2 in the DNS that server3 is using.  If you don't want to edit DNS like that then edit the hosts file on server3 and add a reference in to pointing to server2's name and IP address.